# How to reinitialize Boost Log library on fork?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, fork, boost-log

[Boost.Log does not support fork()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/fork_support.html). This is kind of unbelievable, but a [ticket comment](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/boost-log/ticket/16) describes a workaround:

> [..] so for now it's up to users to reinitialize the library at fork. You can use pthread_atfork to do such reinitialization.

Thus my question: how exactly do I re-initialize Boost.Log after a fork()?

Code example much appreciated.

Comment: @marathon, unfortunately, no, I did not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of all the sinks, and recreate them in the `pthread_atfork` handler *in the child* process_. I.e. the `add_console_log` or `add_file_log` functions return a `boost::shared_ptr` to the sink. Reset that, and initialize 
it again.

```
...
boost::shared_ptr<
    sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend >
> console_sink = logging::add_console_log();
...
void fork_child_handler(void)
{
    console_sink = logging::add_console_log();
    return;
}

// in some global setup code of your application
pthread_atfork(NULL /*prepare*/, 
               NULL /* parent */, 
               &fork_child_handler);
```

Take care, that `fork` may leave more things behind than just broken
log sink. Stay away from multi-threading and `fork` by all means
(its some irony that pthread library provides the handler for fork,
 which you want to avoid if there are threads ...).